# add custom where condition with user in easyquery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

How can I add a custom where condition with loggedin user_id in easyquery? This is a MVC3 web application. I need to prevent the users to see only there data.

[easyQuery](http://devtools.korzh.com/easyquery/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use BuildSQLEx() method.

Example:

```
  SqlQueryBuilder builder = new SqlQueryBuilder((DbQuery)query);
  builder.BuildSQLEx("", "users.user_id=" + loggedUser.id);
  string sql = builder.Result.SQL;
```